# Highlighting Text in a .net Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, browser, highlighting

I'd like to highlight certain words in the document displayed in an embedded webbrowser control. I can envision a solution where the innerhtml property of the document is modified to add a colorizing < span > tag around the desired text, but I can't help feeling that there must be a simpler way?

Comment: If there is a simpler way I'd like to know about it because that is exactly how I've implemented this in the past.

Comment: How does one work around the problem when the keyword is already located within an <a> or <span> tag?  What's the best way to make that determination without writing a full blown html parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a control in which I used the [Menees Diff Library](http://www.menees.com/index.html) to identify where differences occur (changes, additions, subtractions) and then I inserted spans at the appropriate locations starting from the end of the documents and going in reverse where the spans had an associated CSS class name.

I don't know if there was an easier way, but the solution above suited my needs and didn't take more than a couple hours to implement.  I did some research before implementing but found nothing.